# How to get top 10 and ORDER BY() from COUNT()

Tags: sql

The image below is an example of the database I have to work with.

There are more fields to the database - userid goes till USER-0050

What I want to achieve is a top 10 user activity. Based on the image above the desired output is:

```
User ID           Transaction
USER-005           14
USER-001           12
USER-002           12
USER-003           8
USER-004           6
```

What I have tried so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (userid), count(TCODE) as Transaction
FROM SAP_SECURITY_LOG
GROUP BY TCODE, USERID
```

However my output isn't what I want to achieve. I get

```
UserID    Transaction
User-001     0
User-001     1
User-001     2
User-001     3
User-001     6
```

Basically I want to merge all these together and then get the top 10 transactions of all userids (of all 50 userids)

Any guidance is appreciated. I hope what I'm trying to say makes sense
[image: Image 1]

My output:

[image: Image 2]

Keeps going till user-0050

Comment: What database are you using (MySQl, Oracle, ...)

Comment: And also add example data and expected result for more than just one user.

Comment: My database was given to me in an excel sheet and from then I've managed to get it into MS Access...if that helps

I've added more data and expected result for multiple users

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.   Working with the data you provided, the outcome you wrote is a SUM of the transaction id's for each user.  If I understand correctly you want the Top10 active users - the users with the most transactions..

Comment: what I was trying to achieve - the total transactions per userID - What I  couldn't work out was to then find the top 10 - eliminating #11-50 from the output if possible

Comment: append order by ... desc in your query

Comment: To limit the results, use `LIMIT`, I provided a query with working example in my answer below. It does exactly what you describe: showing the 10 users with the most transactions in your table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Top active users :

```
SELECT Top(10) userid, count(TCODE) as Transaction
FROM SAP_SECURITY_LOG
GROUP BY userID
ORDER BY count(TCODE) DESC
```

Comment: Add a `TOP 10` after the `SELECT` and the OP should get its desired top 10 user activities listed ...

Answer (score 2):

- You can use `ORDER BY` in combination with `DESC` (descending) to order the results.
- You can use `LIMIT` to limit the results to a certain amount, eg: `LIMIT 10`.
- To make your code easier to read (and easier for us to make suggestions), you want to be consistent with your upper/lower case (eg. use upper case for SQL keywords).

So you could use `ORDER BY transaction DESC LIMIT 10` to achieve your desired results.

Your code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (userid), count(TCODE) as Transaction
FROM SAP_SECURITY_LOG
GROUP BY TCODE, USERID
```

Your code using my suggestions:

```
SELECT userid, COUNT(tcode) as transactions_count
FROM sap_security_log
GROUP BY userid
ORDER BY transactions_count DESC LIMIT 10
```

I made a working example with my suggestion so you can see what the query does: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2cc33/1/0

Answer (score 1):

You can Obtain the top ten users  using TOP

```
SELECT TOP  10 userid, count(TCODE) as Transaction
FROM SAP_SECURITY_LOG
GROUP BY  USERID
ORDER BY count(TCODE)  DESC ;
```

Comment: You don't need `DISTINCT` if you already use `GROUP BY` ..... plus: if you have `GROUP BY TCODE, USERID`, you'll get the results the OP is showing which is **NOT** what he's looking for.....